# SQL SERVER - TCP an OLE DB Provider Errors

Tags: sql-server, tcp, oledb, linked-server, sqlncli

I'm using a Linked Server to execute remote queries between two DBs on different servers. Both DBs are SQL SERVER. However, I'm getting the following errors:

1 - TCP Provider: **The semaphore timeout period has expired.**

2 - OLE DB Provider: **"SQLNCLI10" for linked server "xxx" returned message: "communication link failure".**

The queries are executed through C# and these errors occur sporadically, not all the time. Also, I'm executing the same code/queries with another linked server and none of these errors have occured. Both linked servers are configured the same way. The code has been running for 72 hours on both machines. 
I can't understand why the errors happen. So, any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Not an SQL Server issue - its a network issue between the server and the linked server either at the physical or adapter level.  If you are running older server versions see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942861/

Comment: What does it actually mean and how can it be solved?